# Is this possible to map results from one SFDX command to another SFDX command?

Tags: salesforcedx, sfdx-plugin, jq

What I am trying to do is to automatize a process of passing results from one SFDX command to another SFDX command and I struggle to implement that.

My source command is

```
sfdx force:package:installed:list -u sourceOrg
```

I could even run JSON variant of it like

```
sfdx force:package:installed:list -u sourceOrg --json
```

so that it returns me a json data which I can then assign to a javascript variable and select `SubscriberPackageVersionId` of these results

```
var a = {
  "status": 0,
  "result": [
  {
      "Id": "0A3E00000002ricKAA",
      "SubscriberPackageId": "033300000004PVbAAM",
      "SubscriberPackageName": "License Management App",
      "SubscriberPackageNamespace": "sfLma",
      "SubscriberPackageVersionId": "04t30000001DWL0AAO",
      "SubscriberPackageVersionName": "1.20",
      "SubscriberPackageVersionNumber": "1.20.0.1"
    },
    {
      "Id": "0A3E00000002rigKAA",
      "SubscriberPackageId": "033A0000000PB5YIAW",
      "SubscriberPackageName": "DocuSign For Salesforce",
      "SubscriberPackageNamespace": "dsfs",
      "SubscriberPackageVersionId": "04tA0000000SEKIIA4",
      "SubscriberPackageVersionName": "6.6.4",
      "SubscriberPackageVersionNumber": "6.6.4.2"
    }
  ]
}
a.result.map(x=>x.SubscriberPackageVersionId)
```

Then using results of `a.result.map(x=>x.SubscriberPackageVersionId)` I could pass it to the destination command like following

```
FOR %%P IN (04t30000001DWL0AAO,04tA0000000SEKIIA4) DO sfdx force:package:install -i %%P -u %1 -r -w 1
```

I am struggling to automatize this but not sure how this can be automated.

Should I write some custom SFDX plugin? I have seen a question about how one can [execute an existing SFDX command inside a SFDX plugin but there was no definite answer](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/222187/is-it-possible-to-call-an-sfdx-plugin-or-command-from-an-sfdx-plugin?rq=1), so, looks like it is impossible or I don't understand how to implement that.

Should I use `jq`? I am not able to install `jq` on windows and not able to run any commands from `jq`. Even if I had `jq` installed, I would still struggle how to use it for my case.

Answer (score 1):

Figured out how to pass the result of the first command into `jq` on `windows`

```
sfdx force:package:installed:list -u sourceOrg --json | ~/Downloads/jq.exe '.result[].SubscriberPackageVersionId'
```

Found a bash script which would run the conversion I was looking for

```
for a in $(sfdx force:package:installed:list -u sourceOrg --json | ~/Downloads/jq.exe -r '.result[].SubscriberPackageVersionId'); do 
echo $a
sfdx force:package:install -p $a -u destOrg -r -w 1000; 
done
```