# capture sfdx command errors

Tags: salesforcedx, sfdx-plugin

One could call a sfdx command from a salesforce [sfdx plugin](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.sfdx_cli_plugins.meta/sfdx_cli_plugins/cli_plugins_intro_what_is_plugin.htm), for example:

```
import Report from "@salesforce/plugin-apex/lib/commands/force/apex/test/report";
...
export default class AllureReport extends SfdxCommand {
  ...
  public async run(): Promise<AnyJson> {
    const config: any = {};
    const reportCmd = new Report(["-i", testRunId], config);
    await reportCmd._run();
    console.log("hello world");
  }
}
```

[Source](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/222187/is-it-possible-to-call-an-sfdx-plugin-or-command-from-an-sfdx-plugin)

In this case if the line `await reportCmd._run()` fails, then the command Report does not throw an error message, it just outputs some logs. This means that the line `console.log("hello world")` will execute even if the report command fails. How can I capture/detect the error? I checked the report object properties but I do not see any flag that indicates failure.